# How to solve the ERROR: usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py error running the SHAP test-cases with PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, shap

I cannot get around this error while trying to run the shap test-cases with PyCharm:

```
/home/user/shap/venv/bin/python /home/user/Desktop/pycharm-community-2021.1.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --path /home/user/shap/tests
Testing started at 10:51 a.m. ...
Launching pytest with arguments /home/user/shap/tests in /home/user/shap/tests

ERROR: usage: _jb_pytest_runner.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
_jb_pytest_runner.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mpl --cov=shap --cov-report=term-missing
  inifile: /home/user/shap/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /home/user/shap


Process finished with exit code 4

Empty suite
```

I have tried different installations (pytest, pip and conda). I have also tried different Python versions as well as shap versions. Nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check if you have coverage and pytest-cov installed (pip). Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The answer is simple.
Install everything using the PyCharm (Settings->Project->Project Interpreter, and press +) and not the pip (or other) from the command line.

Comment: This is not a clear solution to what causes the problem nor an actual fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove/Comment from pytest.ini the line of code how contains --mpl --cov=shap --cov-report=term-missing
Run again and now work (i hope)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).